# How to Add superscript value in YII2 dropdownlist

Tags: php, yii2, dropdown, superscript

Here the Example

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'volume')->dropDownList(['m3'=>'m3','bbls'=>'bbls','gallons'=>'gallons','litres'=>'litres' ],array('prompt'=>'--Select Volume Unit --')) ?>
```

Need 3 in superscript,Like M<sup>3</sup> IN Option Text

I Tried but its not work in normal dropdown and in YII2 Dropdown

Thanks In Advance

Comment: How would you do it with HTML only?

Comment: this has nothing to do with yii, try using [`Unicode values`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/superscripts_and_subscripts/list.htm) given if the appropriate fonts are installed, use them like `m&U+2083;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select element is rendered by the OS, not HTML. It cannot be modified using aditional HTML tags.

However in this case you can use HTML Entity to use font related super/sub script:

```
 <select>
  <option value="m3">m&#179;</option>
  <option value="m4">m&#8308;</option>
</select>
```

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g0tbmrbf/3/)

> HTML: **<sup>3</sup>**
>   HTML entity: **&#179;**
>   JavaScript: **\u00B3**
>   JavaScript: **\xB3**

[Unicode Character 'SUPERSCRIPT THREE' (U+00B3)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00B3/index.htm)

Comment: Thanks ino its working,how can i implement this in Yii2

Comment: Not tested in Yii2 but try replacing the `'m3'=>'m3'` with `'m3'=>'m&#179;'`

Comment: There are several ways of writing the special characters... Let's try this notation of the superscript three: `'m3'=>'m\u00B3'` . I have updated the live demo as well.